# I am not able to implement a SQL Server stored procedure for a specific output

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, crystal-reports

My stored procedure is as follows:-

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_crystal_project_order_dtf_dttax]
     @id int
AS BEGIN
     SELECT  
         tbltax.taxname, ROUND(tbltax.taxamount,2) AS 'taxamount'
     FROM 
         (SELECT
              'Sub Total:' as 'taxname',
              sub_total1_factory as 'taxamount',
              -10 as 'OrderCol'
          FROM
              project_order_rewise
          WHERE
              project_order_rewise.[id] = @id

          UNION

          SELECT
              'Less Discount @ ' + cast(isnull([discount], 0) AS varchar(max)) + '%:' as 'taxname',
              (sub_total1_factory * isnull([discount], 0) / 100) AS 'taxamount',
              -9
          FROM
              [dbo].project_order_rewise
          WHERE
              [dbo].project_order_rewise.[id] = @id

          UNION

          SELECT
              'Packaging / Forwarding:' as 'taxname',
              transportation_charges_factory as 'taxamount',
              -8
          FROM
              project_order_rewise
          WHERE
              project_order_rewise.[id] = @id 

          UNION 

    select 'Sub Total:' as 'taxname'
            ,sub_total2_factory as 'taxamount'
            ,-7
    from [dbo].project_order_rewise
    where [dbo].project_order_rewise.[id]=@id

    union

    select 'Add '+[tax_master].[tax_name]+ ' @ '+cast([tax_value].[value]as varchar(max))+'%:' as 'taxname'
           ,project_order_tax.[amt_factory] as 'taxamount'
           ,-6
    from project_order_rewise inner join (tax_master inner join (project_order_tax inner join tax_value
        on project_order_tax.tax_value = tax_value.id)
        on tax_master.id=tax_value.tax_id)
        on project_order_rewise.id=project_order_tax.pro_order_rewise_id
    where project_order_rewise.id=@id 

    union

    select 'Sub Total:' as 'taxname'
            ,sub_total3_factory as 'taxamount'
            ,-5
    from project_order_rewise
    where project_order_rewise.[id]=@id

    union

    select 'Transportation Charges:' as 'taxname'
            ,newtransportchrg as 'taxamount'
            ,-4
    from project_order_rewise
    where project_order_rewise.[id]=@id

    union

    select 'Sub Total:' as 'taxname'
            ,subtotalwithtrans as 'taxamount'
            ,-3
    from project_order_rewise
    where project_order_rewise.[id]=@id

    union

    select 'Add '+[tax_master].[tax_name]+ ' @ '+cast([tax_value].[value]as varchar(max))+'%:' as 'taxname'
           ,project_order_tax1.[amount] as 'taxamount'
           ,-2
    from project_order_rewise inner join (tax_master inner join (project_order_tax1 inner join tax_value
        on project_order_tax1.tax_value = tax_value.id)
        on tax_master.id=tax_value.tax_id)
        on project_order_rewise.id=project_order_tax1.pro_order_rewise_id
    where project_order_rewise.id=@id 

    union

        select 'Grand Total:' as 'taxname'
            ,grandtotal1 as 'taxamount'
            ,-1
    from project_order_rewise
    where project_order_rewise.[id]=@id

    ) as tbltax

    order by OrderCol
end

exec sp_crystal_project_order_dtf_dttax 60
```

It returns this output:

```
taxname                      taxamount
---------------------------------------
Sub Total:                     220
Less Discount @ 0.00%:           0
Packaging / Forwarding:          0
Sub Total:                     220
Add Excise Duty @ 12.36%:       27.19
Sub Total:                     247.19
Transportation Charges:          0
Sub Total:                     247.19
Grand Total:                   247.19
```

I have implemented my procedure in this way because I want to display it in a
crystal report.I don't want the result of a select clause where 'taxamount', discount,Packaging / Forwarding,tax,transportation charges is 0.I don't want to show that result. When I used where clause

```
where taxamount <> 0 or taxamount <> null
```

result displayed like:

```
taxname                       taxamount
---------------------------------------
Sub Total:                    220
Add Excise Duty @ 12.36%:      27.19
Grand Total:                  247.19
```

When I executed page in google chrome. In Crystal Reports result is shown like this:

```
taxname                      taxamount
--------------------------------------
Sub Total:                     220
Sub Total:                     220
Sub Total:                     220
Sub Total:                     220
Add Excise Duty @ 12.36%:       27.19
Sub Total:                     247.19
Sub Total:                     247.19
Sub Total:                     247.19
Grand Total:                   247.19
```

Can anybody tell me the solution to this.

Comment: At least to me it's difficult to understand what your actual problem is. Also, if you want help with your SQL, you should setup an example into SQL Fiddle.

Comment: It's also not recommended to use sp_ as the procedure prefix because it has a special meaning, it's supposed to be used for the system procedures.

Comment: I have to agree with @JamesZ. As posted this just doesn't make any sense at all. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Where in the code did you put the where clause that caused the issue?